# Optimisation in Java Using Apache Commons Math

Tags: java, optimization, apache-commons, solver, apache-commons-math

I'm trying to minimise a value in Java using`commons-math`. I've had a look at their [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/leastsquares.html) but I don't really get how to implement it.

Basically, in my code below, I have a `Double` which has the expected goals in a soccer match and I'd like to optimise the probability value of under 3 goals occurring in a game to 0.5.

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.PoissonDistribution;

public class Solver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Double expectedGoals = 2.9d;
        final PoissonDistribution poissonGoals = new PoissonDistribution(expectedGoals);

        Double probabilityUnderThreeGoals = 0d;

        for (int score = 0; score < 15; score++) {
            final Double probability =
                    poissonGoals.probability(score);
            if (score < 3) {
                probabilityUnderThreeGoals = probabilityUnderThreeGoals + probability;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(probabilityUnderThreeGoals); //prints 0.44596319855718064, I want to optimise this to 0.5
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `expectedGoals = 2.67406` (if I understand correctly)? Also, note you can use `cumulativeProbability(2)` and don't need the loop.

Comment: @Sweeper yes, 2.67406 is the correct value- but I was wondering how to implement the optimization algorithm for future cases when trial and error isn't so straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cumulative probability (<= x) of a Poisson random variable can be calculated by:

[image]

In your case, x is 2 and you want to find lambda (the mean) such that this is 0.5. You can [type this into WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E%28-x%29%2Be%5E%28-x%29*x%2Be%5E%28-x%29*x%5E2%2F2%3D0.5&lang=ja) and have it solve it for you. So rather than an optimisation problem, this is just a root-finding problem (though one could argue that optimisation problems *are* just finding roots.)

You can also do this with Apache Commons Maths, with one of the [root finders](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html).

```
int maximumGoals = 2;
double expectedProbability = 0.5;
UnivariateFunction f = x -> {
  double sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= maximumGoals; i++) {
    sum += Math.pow(x, i) / CombinatoricsUtils.factorialDouble(i);
  }
  return sum * Math.exp(-x) - expectedProbability;
};

// the four parameters that "solve" takes are:
// the number of iterations, the function to solve, min and max of the root
// I've put some somewhat sensible values as an example. Feel free to change them
double answer = new BisectionSolver().solve(Integer.MAX_VALUE, f, 0, maximumGoals / expectedProbability);
System.out.println("Solved: " + answer);
System.out.println("Cumulative Probability: " + new PoissonDistribution(answer).cumulativeProbability(maximumGoals));
```

This prints:

```
Solved: 2.674060344696045
Cumulative Probability: 0.4999999923623868
```